# Does cron maintain an in-memory directory cache?

Tags: linux, cron

We run a large distributed Linux computing environment where a user's home directory may be moved between different back-end filestores due to their affiliation and general distribution between different fileservers. As a result of this, their homedirectory may be changed from something like /fileserver1/joeuser to /fileserver3/joeuser.

After going through processes of copying the files, `sethome` is used to set their home directory. After a logout/login, their $HOME and ~ variables are both pointing to the new path and everything is going as it should.

Cron, however, appears to still think that ~ refers to their old home directory and will fail when constructing a path using that outdated information.

We suspect that this is due to some sort of internal in-memory directory caching on behalf of the cron daemon.

For a number of reasons, we'd like to avoid restarting crond on a regular basis, and would prefer to refer to ~ so that they can construct paths in their crontabs.

Any other solutions out there, or insights to this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Cron takes the home directory `~` from wherever `/etc/nsswitch.conf` says to get the user info. This will be shown with `getent passwd <username>`

`$HOME` isnt the same as `~`

Answer (score 1):

Any caching of this sort would likely be done by the Linux `nscd` daemon.  Restart it to clear its cache.

The cron daemon has no code to cache things like previously automounted directories and does not retain any contents of system variables by the person who edited the cron table.